# Can't route to loginform

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-form

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../../redux/reducer';
import { LoginForm } from '../LoginForm/LoginForm';
import { About } from '../About/About';
import { Companies } from '../Companies/Companies';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './HomePage.css';



class HomePage extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
       <div className="backgrnd" >

       <h1><blink> MULTIHAND ONLINE IT WORLD</blink></h1>

       <h3 className="outside"><marquee> New Evolution Rising Up.. Your Complete Business,Carrier & Developing Partner..</marquee></h3>

  <Router>
    <div className="banner" >
  <div >
    <ul>
       <li><Link className="a" to='/'>•Home</Link></li>
       <li><Link className="a" to='/About'>•About</Link></li>     
       <li><Link className="a" to='/LoginForm'>•Login</Link></li>
       <li><Link className="a" to='/Companies'>•Companies</Link></li>
       <li><Link className="a" to='/services'>•Services</Link></li>
       <li><Link className="a" to='/contact'>•Contact</Link></li>
     </ul>
    </div>

      <hr/>

      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/loginForm" component={LoginForm}/>
      <Route path="/companies" component={Companies}/>
      <Route path="/services" component={Services}/>
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>

  </Router>

 </div>

    );
  }
}

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <div className="wrapper">
    <div className="row">
    <div className="ann"><div className="blink"><span>ANNOUNCEMENTS<br></br></span></div>*New launching of IT company Martl park Solutions in howel Building 2nd Floor @12.00pm on 12th May 2018</div>
    <div className="ann1"><div className="blink"><span>VACCANCIES </span></div>*No new Openings</div>
    <div className="ann2"><div className="blink"><span>Today's Highest Closing Company </span></div><b>*Tata </b></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);




const Services = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Services</h2>
  </div>
);

const Contact = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <h3 className="inside">MULTIHAND ONLINE IT WORLD</h3>
    <h4>Tech Arcade Building </h4>
    <h4>Inside Technopark</h4>
    <h4>Kazhakuttam P.O</h4>
    <h4> Thiruvanathapuram </h4>
    <hr/>
    <h4 className="con"> ☏:- +91-9854631278</h4>
    <h4 className="con"> ✉:- online@multihandworld.com</h4>

  </div>
);

export default HomePage;
```

This is my Homepage.js I want to route to login page after clicking login button. Same as for about and companies, But it doesn't works. The page is still load in homepage.. It doesn't redirect to any other page.. What all changes that I need to make in my code to run properly? Is it anything wrong in my code? This is my project path:

[image: This is my Project path]

I want to route to LoginForm.js in LoginForm folder. Is there need to change code in any other page? Is there anyone willing to help me? It's become a great relief..

Also this is my index.js page

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage/HomePage';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <HomePage/>

  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Also my About.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './About.css';



class About extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <p>Here we are giving a complete view of all growing technical companies in European Countries those which are registered under our site. We assure this site are very useful and time saving for your bright future..We hope you enjoy browsing through our area..</p> 
            );
    }
}
export default About;
```

LoginForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../../redux/reducer';
import './LoginForm.css';



class LoginForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    let {username, password} = this.state;
    let {isLoginPending, isLoginSuccess, loginError} = this.props;

    return (
          <div>

         <header>
   <h1>Company Login</h1>
   </header>
      <form name="loginForm" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

        <div className="imgcontainer">
    <img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" className="avatar"/>
  </div>

        <div className="form-group-collection">
          <div className="form-group">

            <label>Username/User ID:</label>
            <input name="username" onChange={e => this.setState({username: e.target.value})} value={username}/>
          </div>


          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value})} value={password}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />

  </form>
     <footer>Copyright &copy; multihands.com. </footer>
     </div> 
    )
  }






  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.login(username, password);
    this.setState({
      username: '',
      password: ''
    });
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoginPending: state.isLoginPending,
    isLoginSuccess: state.isLoginSuccess,
    loginError: state.loginError
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    login: (username, password) => dispatch(login(username, password))
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Comment: where is your LoginForm component? Could you please write that too?

Comment: Ya ofcourse, it's done....

Comment: Oh great. Let others know too how you did. Someday someone might come across this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove two dots `..` from the path

```
<MenuLink to="/LoginForm" label="LoginForm" />
<Route path="/LoginForm" component={Login}/>
```

Comment: May I send a zip file of my project?

Comment: Sorry, no. Try to create sandbox with simple version of your app where your problem can be reproduced, in most cases it helps to find out the fix by your own.

Answer (score 0):

Your `path={}` and `to={}` are not related to folder hierarchy, they represent what would be in the url. If you want the users to be directed to "localhost:3000/loginform" your 'to' would be `to="/loginform"`.

So an example router would be:

```
<Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/loginform" component={Login}/>
    <Route path="/gallery" component={Gallery}/>
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
</Router>
```

And then create a link somewhere such as:

```
<div className="menu">
    <Link to="/loginform">Login</Link>
    <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
    //...and so on...
</div>
```

EDIT -- new router example:

```
<Router>
    <div className="banner">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link className="a" to='/'>•Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="a" to='/about'>•About</Link></li>     
                <li><Link className="a" to='/loginform'>•Login</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="a" to='/companies'>•Companies</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="a" to='/services'>•Services</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="a" to='/contact'>•Contact</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/loginform" component={LoginForm}/>
            <Route path="/companies" component={Companies}/>
            <Route path="/services" component={Services}/>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message or are the links just not working?

Comment: You're links and paths don't match, I've updated my answer with a new router for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169581/discussion-between-edward-mish-and-will).